# Is it possible to build your own Python embedded distribution from source

Tags: python, deployment, packaging

I'm interested if it's possible to (easily) roll/build/compile my own [Python embedded distribution](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution) for Windows but with the modules I'm interested in.

I have never liked the tools like PyInstaller, Py2exe, or Cx_Freeze because they often get confused or not work exactly the way I want it to.

I've compiled Python from source before but not in the same way that the Python embedded distribution is released.

I hate having to distribute Python-based tools bundled with the runtime but pip isn't an option for deployment here.